Fairy princess selects a former lover as life partner with whom their powers arose and formed a child
Story is set in a background of fairy kingdom, where a princess who is set to be the successor celebrates her a milestone birthday (18 or 21) where she has to select a life partner.
She then selects a girl, the whole kingdom is shocked but even more shocked is the girl who is selected. She hates the princess and she assumes the princess is taking revenge in the form of marriage. They were later revealed to be childhood best friends turned lovers then broke up.
It later reveals that the first time they were intimate act coincides with the arousal of the fae power for both and they lose consciousness and for the princess who is the powerful of them all releases a great amount of energy. It leads to the combination of their energy and that energy forms a child (I know looks absurd but after reading the book you'll be convinced). But the girl when woke up won't find princess and assumes she left her naked and alone.
After she finds she's pregnant she believes someone SA ed her, after princess left (which later reveals to be wrong and in fact the unexpected miracle happened). She'll have the child which raised away from her through the aunt of princess. Later the princess finds out and brings the child they both reconciliated after knowing the truth.
It is trilogy and 2 books have released.
